# join/search/sum in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

i'm new to Panda and trying to learn it, I have a DataFrame in Panda with 3 different columns:

```
   a             b         c
-----------------------------
'     Alice   5/5/2014     2 '
'     Bob     7/18/2014    1 '
'     Alice   5/5/2014     3 '
'     Bob     8/10/2014    5 '
------------------------------
```

I want to sum up the 'C' columns for each person per month, so the desired result would be like :

```
   a             b         c
-----------------------------
'     Alice   5/5/2014     5 '
'     Bob     7/18/2014    1 '
'     Bob     8/10/2014    5 '
------------------------------
```

what is the best way to do this in Panda.

if my question is repeated please re-direct me to other question i couln't find it maybe because i wasn't sure what to look for. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way is to first make sure your date column is of a `datetime` type:

```
>>> df2
       a          b  c
0  Alice   5/5/2014  2
1    Bob  7/18/2014  1
2  Alice   5/9/2014  3
3    Bob  8/10/2014  5
>>> df2['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.b)
```

Then, index the `DataFrame` by the date column:

```
>>> df2.set_index('b',inplace=True)
>>> df2
                a  c
b                   
2014-05-05  Alice  2
2014-07-18    Bob  1
2014-05-09  Alice  3
2014-08-10    Bob  5
```

Then use `groupby`:

```
>>> df2.groupby(['a',df2.index.month]).sum()
         c
a         
Alice 5  5
Bob   7  1
      8  5
>>>
```

And you can always go back to your original index:

```
>>> df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> df2
           b      a  c
0 2014-05-05  Alice  2
1 2014-07-18    Bob  1
2 2014-05-09  Alice  3
3 2014-08-10    Bob  5
```

Comment: this is better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

add a column specifying the month

```
df['month'] = df['b'].month   # assuming it's a datetime object
```

then groupby and sum

```
df.groupby(['a','month']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function like:

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b']).sum()
```

> Group series using mapper (dict or key function, apply given function to group, return result as series) or by a series of columns.